# Php and mysql used tree div for one area

Tags: php, mysql, css, database

i want to learn one think.

First of all i have tree type div and one main div.

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="first-div"></div>
  <div class="secont-div"></div>
  <div class="thirt-div"></div
</div>
```

First div for cover photo, second div is image gallery and thirt div is metro empty.

the user will select the three type segments.

If user want to use first div user porfile show only first div. If user want to use other one div user profile show that div. 
when user click on div1 display this div and hide others div2 and div3, and when user click on div2 display this div and hide others div1 and div3. I want to use it in php and mysql

Comment: `I want to use any of these three parts to the user how can I write a code in php ?`, what does mean this?

Comment: @SumanBogati the user will select the three segments

Comment: Your question is not so clear, please explain it with more details.

Comment: Basically you meant so say when user click on `div1` display this div and hide others `div2` and `div3`, and when user click on `div2` display this div and hide others `div1` and `div3`, am I right?

Comment: @SumanBogati yes dear thank you . Sorry for my english

Comment: so for this you need to use javascript, is it okay for you?

Comment: @SumanBogati yes if you know example tutorial can you tell me or if you know how can i do this ?

Comment: Yes i can do it for you, but one question when user click on `div1`, other divs are hide then how can you click on `div2` or `div3`?

Comment: Please have look the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to gues what do you really need!
This is the practice of writing php dynamicly...

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="first-div"><?php echo'<img src="path to your image">'; ?></div>
  <div class="secont-div"><?php echo'<img src="path to your image">'; ?></div>
  <div class="thirt-div"></div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Maybe this!?
This is jquery library! You can find it at https://jqueryui.com/accordion/
JUst copy and pate the code in the document

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for reply . I am asking div close open. For example if user want to use first div he/she click use this div and automatically close another div.

Comment: when user click on div1 display this div and hide others div2 and div3, and when user click on div2 display this div and hide others div1 and div3

Answer (score 0):

Well I am supposing there is button after click on which, all the divs would dislay, and when you click on any div, the clicked div would display and othere would be hidden.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PABN8/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="coreDiv" class="main-div">
  <div id="div1" class="first-div" onclick="divAction('div1')">div1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="secont-div" onclick="divAction('div2')">div2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="thirt-div"onclick="divAction('div3')">div3</div>
  <button onclick="showAllDiv()">Show all Div</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function divAction(id){
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('coreDiv'); 
    allDivs = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i=0; i<allDivs.length; i++){
        if(allDivs[i].id == id){
            allDivs[i].style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            allDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

function showAllDiv(){
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('coreDiv'); 
    allDivs = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i=0; i<allDivs.length; i++){
        allDivs[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: why you wanted in php? Php means you should control which div should display at loading of page.

Comment: I think there is no use of php on clicking `div1` and display this and hide others.

Comment: because this question for user profile. for example user click to use div2 another div hide. but when user refresh the page div1 div2 and div3 is come again.I want to do to be used for the desired record button

Comment: Then you should use the ajax, clicking on `div1` you should inform about this to `php` and it updates `div1` is active div on server side, now when refresh the page, your `php` code handle only the active div `div1` should be display.